# using ng-options within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular and I'm confused over this thing. I'm trying to populate a select box based on object inside an array. I want selectbox by using ng-repeat for that array... but initially i need to show only one selectbox after clicking add() next selectbox has to come.  for ref:[initially one selectbox has to come]

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="variant1" style="margin-top:10px" ng-repeat="variant in variants">
       <div class="col-lg-4" style="text-align:right;padding-top:2px;padding-right: 20px" >
          <label  for="variant1name">Variant Name</label>
       </div>

       <div class="col-lg-6" >
          <div   >
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="filterFormInputs.apps" ng-options="app.Application for app in variants" >
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select an Application</option> 
             </select>
             <label ng-repeat="checkbox in filterFormInputs.apps.details">
                <input class="ecomtexttype1" type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox.checked"> {{checkbox.name}}
             </label>                
          </div>
       </div>         
     </div>
```

**Controller**:

```
$scope.variants =
[
    {"Application": "Color", "details":[{"name":"red"},{"name":"blue"},{"name":"black"}]},
    {"Application": "Color", "details":[{"name":"red"},{"name":"blue"},{"name":"black"}]},
    {"Application": "Color", "details":[{"name":"red"},{"name":"blue"},{"name":"black"}]}
]
```

Comment: Is there any limit ? or any number of rows can be added??

Comment: yea by using some function to add new objects to the array.. and no limit

Comment: code which you exposed is not enough! Can you add some more code. or shall we connect via team viewer? Your solution is simple, but takes little time to fix in a new code. that is the reason I am asking so..

Comment: which part u want to view?

Comment: your controller method for the adding the row.

Comment: found the answer for that issue.. i used seperate array for ng-repeat...... thnkz @Aravind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can just have your `add()` function update the array... if things are configured correctly the new row should render due to the binding on the array.

As mentioned in comments you did not provide enough source code, so here is the assumed pseudo-code:

in html you might have

```
<button ng-click="$scope.add()">Add</button>
```

so in the controller

```
$scope.variants = [
  // array of whatever you are displaying
  {"foo":"bar1"},
  {"foo":"bar2"}
];

$scope.add = function() {
  variants.push({"foo":"bar_new"});
}
```

Have you considered using a Directive for this? That may work better, depending on your situation. Look into this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive